# Discord.js creating a new channel returns "Invalid Form Body"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a bot for my girlfriend's online store to automate order placing / tracking and I've run into a bit of a stumping issue. Maybe it's silly and I'm over looking something because of my unfamiliarity with discord v14 and it's intents.

Anyways, here's the code I use to create the new channel:

```js
// populate the order than handle the return functionality
manager.populateOrder(cid, orderNumber, async (err, code) => {
  // if there was an issue, handle general logging
  if (err) {
    logger.error(err);
    await message.channel.send({
      embeds: [embeds.error(code)],
    });
    return;
  }

  // create the private channel
  message.guild.channels
    .create(`order-${orderNumber}`, {
      type: "text",
      permissionOverwrites: [
        {
          id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
          deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
        },
        {
          id: message.author.id,
          allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
        },
      ],
    })
    .catch(async (err) => {
      await logger.error(err);
      await console.log(err);

      await message.channel.send({
        embeds: [embeds.error("DC-4API-OR")],
      });
    })
    .then(async (channel) => {
      await channel.send({
        embeds: [
          embeds.embed(
            "Customize your order",
            "You may customize your order or simply enter the ID to one of our pre-made items."
          ),
        ],
      });
      await message.channel.send({
        embeds: [
          embeds.embed(
            "You have opened up a new order with us!",
            "Head over to the channel and tell us what you would like, and we will get to you ASAP."
          ),
        ],
      });
    });
});
```

Here's the error that's being thrown when I try and execute the command:

```
[Error] Invalid Form Body
name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\speci\Desktop\Lilac Lullaby\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:293:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\speci\Desktop\Lilac Lullaby\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\speci\Desktop\Lilac Lullaby\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:52:22)
    at async GuildChannelManager.create (C:\Users\speci\Desktop\Lilac Lullaby\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildChannelManager.js:145:18) {
  rawError: {
    code: 50035,
    errors: { name: [Object] },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/1015719976210018394/channels',
  requestBody: {
    files: undefined,
    json: {
      name: undefined,
      topic: undefined,
      type: undefined,
      nsfw: undefined,
      bitrate: undefined,
      user_limit: undefined,
      parent_id: undefined,
      position: undefined,
      permission_overwrites: undefined,
      rate_limit_per_user: undefined,
      rtc_region: undefined,
      video_quality_mode: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

I've looked around online and haven't found anything that explains exactly why this is happening. I understand that a value isn't being passed properly somewhere, but I can't figure out where and why. My best guess is it's something to do with my bot's intents // permissions. So, I tried giving the bot all the intents I thought it would need, and gave it admin permissions and it still is throwing the same issue.

For reference, here's a list of my registered intents:

```js
// create a client object
const client = new discord.Client({
  // declare our gateway intents
  partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"],
  intents: [
    Object.keys(discord.IntentsBitField.Flags),
    discord.IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    discord.IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildWebhooks,
    discord.IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildIntegrations,
    discord.IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessageTyping,
  ],
});
```

Any insight as to why this is happening and how to go about fixing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't chain your `.then()` handler on to the `.catch()`

Comment: I only put the then handler to mess around with error logging in my server / console. Prior to that I had it surrounded in a try / catch statement and I was still getting the same error. Don't think it's the then chain, but noted on not chaining them to catches.

Comment: Just looks like you got the args for `create()` wrong. See [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create), it's meant to accept a single [options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/GuildChannelCreateOptions) object where the `name` property is required

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After viewing [Phil's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) comment regarding not using the appropriate arguments I looked over the documentation and figured out what arguments were required.

If anyone needs this in the future, here's my updated code:

```js
 // create the private channel
                message.guild.channels.create({
                    name: `order-${orderNumber}`,
                    type: discord.ChannelType.GuildText,
                    permissionOverwrites: [{
                            id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
                            deny: [discord.PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel]
                        },
                        {
                            id: message.author.id,
                            allow: [discord.PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel]
                        }

                    ]
                }).then(async channel => {

                    // move the channel to the orders category, probably going to make this configurable via our mf.json
                    await channel.setParent('1015950001920278548');

                    // send a generic order placing message in the new channel
                    await channel.send({embeds: [embeds.embed("Place your order.", "Hello! Welcome to the order placing channel. Here you may either order precustoms (by id) or make a custom order by talking with our staff. Everything regarding your order from creation to shipping will be done here.")]});

                    // send a message in the executing channel that directs the user to the newly created channel
                    await message.channel.send({embeds: [embeds.embed("We've opened up an order ticket!", `Thanks for wanting to place an order with us. Head on over to <#${channel.id}> and let our staff know what you want!`)]});

                }).catch(async err => {

                    // log the error to our logging system.
                    await logger.error(err);

                    // send the discord api error code
                    await channel.send({embeds: [embeds.error("DC-4API-OR")]})

                });
```

and again, thanks Phil for pointing me in the right direction.